Error when trying to setup node.js express in glitch
I've been using Glitch to host my node.js scripts and when I try and setup node.js, I get an error. I expected to setup express the same way I would with Replit but I'm keep getting the same error. It works fine if I go in the terminal and enter node server.js
The error
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
My server.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
// using example code from expressjs.com

My package.json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node.js": "^10.24.1",
    "express": "^4.19.2"
  }
}

I think something is wrong with my package.json but I have no idea what it is. Also, this is a completely new project meaning there are only these two files and glitches built-in npm libraries.

Did you use npm i express ?
if it doesn't work delete package.json file and use npm init . then npm i express .

So apparently I just needed to install express with the terminal instead of relying on the glitch package manager for npm...

You don't need to add Node as a dependency in the package.json, you only need to set the engine to what version of Node you need. By listing it as a dependency, Glitch was probably spending a bunch of time trying to install this second copy and that's why Express wasn't being installed.

By the way - Node.js is just a security placeholder and not an actual package on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/node.js
